# Want to require 'recent' authentication for a subset of routes to prevent mis-use of bosses PC

Tags: laravel

I have an app that is designed for people to remain authenticated (remember me functionality) (https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#remembering-users), so they can re-open a browser quickly look things up without needing to log in each time.

Some parts of the app allow people to view more sensitive information, or to authorise requests.

I want to prevent people opening a browser on their bosses computer when their boss is out of the room, and accessing this sensitive information.

To be effective I need to stop passwords being cached by browsers - I have worked on this problem before, and overcome it by putting a spurious out-of-viewport password field earlier in the html.

I plan to add an event - as you would have in Laravel 4:

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    $user->last_login = new DateTime;

    $user->save();
});
```

although this is a little more complicated in Laravel 5 but still do-able.

I will then:

add a 'You must have logged in within the last 5 minutes to approve expense claims. Please re-login:' alert div to the login view template that shows in this case only
in the controller methods for tasks that are sensitive, check the authenticated user's users.last_login and if less than X minutes ago, log the user out and redirect them to the current page, which will take them back to the login page displaying the 'you must have logged in in the last 5 minutes...' message).

Does anyone have any experience in other ways to balance security of some funtions/information with convenience of remember me login?

Answer (score 0):

I have made something similar for another reason that could be useful to your request. In the header I added a meta tag 'uid' with the user_id encrypted.

```
<meta name="ui" content="{{ encrypt(Auth::id()) }}"/>
```

With javascript i 'ping' the server every 5 minutes.

```
function ping() {
  const token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  const ui = $('meta[name="ui"]').attr('content');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/ajax/ping',
    data: {'ui': ui},
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}

setInterval(function () {
  ping()
}, 300000);
```

On the server, I decrypt the user_id and log the event in `users.last_activity`. This solution is not cookie based. It will show you who is online, or at least, has been in the last 5 minutes. If they log out/log in, you know right away. If they leave the browser open and do other things, they remain online. If it is more than 5 minutes, you can create a scheduled event (cron job) and log them out on server level.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri - I don't think this solution would assist me in knowing when the last time the person actually entered their password was. If the ping function runs every 5 minutes, then the users.last_activity would just mean they have an open browser window - I want to know the last time they authenticated at the login page.

Comment: A login is server side and can be logged. Middleware can easily update the status during each new action. My solution doesn't really answer your wish, I know, but it's meant as a direction to what you are looking for. 

It can handle non-active browser sessions to whatever you want to achieve, because of back-end awareness. You could reply a jquery handled popup "You will be logged out in 5 minutes" for example. I understood it's for protecting co-workers sessions.